# ChartJS + mysql + php (cadastros no mês)

Tags: php, mysql, query, chartjs

Galera, tenho uma tabela de cadastros de usuários.

Estou criando um chartjs para mostrar em um gráfico de barras o número de usuários cadastrados por mês.

A consulta do mysql teria apenas que me retornar 2 colunas (MÊS e NUMERO TOTAL DE CADASTROS DAQUELE MÊS)

Já tentei de varias formas, mas me retorna muitas colunas :/

Obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

mes (coluna de meses)
id (id dos usuarios)
usuarios (tabela)

```
select mes, count(id) from usuarios group by mes
```

Comment: utilizei da seguinte forma

Comment: select primeira_conversao, count(id) as total from leads WHERE month(primeira_conversao) = 10 group by primeira_conversao

Answer (score 0):

Consegui!

```
select month(primeira_conversao) as mes, year(primeira_conversao) as ano, count(id) as total from leads WHERE month(primeira_conversao) = 11 and year(primeira_conversao) = 2017 group by month(primeira_conversao),year(primeira_conversao)
```